# web method in webservice having object parameters calls dynamic binding

Tags: c#, reflection

I am facing a problem, I have a web method in my web service like this

```
[WebMethod]
public long SaveBusinessUserInfo(UserMaster objUser, UserEmail objEmail,string ouValue)
 {
  // Saving user info in Database    
 }

public Class UserMaster 
{ 
  public string Username{get;set;}
  public string Password{get;set;}
  public string Email{get;set;}
 }

public Class UserEmail 
{ 
  public string Id{get;set;}
  public string Email{get;set;}
  public string Country{get;set;}
 }
```

This all code is in my web service.Now i have to dynamically call this web method on my client end. 
I know how to call a web method which have normal parameter using [this way](http://www.crowsprogramming.com/archives/66), but i don't know how to call Object parametrize function.

Answer (score 0):

In the article you have linked to the following line invokes the web method:

```
(T)type.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, args);
```

The `args` parameter is an `object[]` that must contain the parameters to be passed to your web method. In your particular case you need it to contain 3 elements:

```
UserMaster objUser = ...
UserEmail objEmail = ...
string ouValue = ...
```

and then build the arguments array that will be passed to the method:

```
object[] args = new object[] { objUser, objEmail, ouValue };
```

---

UPDATE:

In order to reference the `UserMaster` and `UserEmail` classes which are defined in your web service you might need to expose all the types that were generated by the client proxy when importing the web service and then use reflection. There's a `Dictionary<string, Type> availableTypes;` property in the `WebServiceInvoker` class which is private in the original example. You could make it public and then you will have access to those types.

So:

WebServiceInvoker invoker = new WebServiceInvoker(new Uri("http://localhost/services/test.php"));

```
string service = "MyService";
string method = "SaveBusinessUserInfo";
Type userMasterType = invoker.AvailableTypes["FullNamespace.UserMaster"];
Type userEmailType = invoker.AvailableTypes["FullNamespace.UserEmail"];
object userMaster = Activator.CreateInstance(userMasterType);
object userEmail = Activator.CreateInstance(userEmailType);

// now that you have obtained the 2 instances you could set properties on them:
userMasterType.GetProperty("Username").SetValue(userMaster, "some username", null);
...

object[] args = new object[] { userMaster, userEmail, "foo bar" };

long result = invoker.InvokeMethod<long>(service, method, args);
```

This could quickly become a nightmare. If you are using .NET 4.0 you could use the [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword to simplify this code.

Comment: UserMaster, UserEmail classes are also in webservce.how can i bind these object at run time..